# Sending http request from aws lambda to google firebse funcitons

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, httprequest

I have set up firebase functions to receive http requests and have verified that the same is working. Now im trying to send http request to firebase from aws lambda function. But there is no response either in aws lambda or in the firebase functions log. This is my aws lambda code:

```
const postData = JSON.stringify({
        "queryresult" : {
          "parameters": {
            "on": "1",
            "device": "1",
            "off": ""
          }
        }
      });

      const options = {
        hostname: 'https://<the firebase function endpoint>',
        port: 443,
        path: '',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
        }
      };

      const req = https.request(options, postData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

      // Write data to request body
      req.write(postData);
      req.end();
    }
```

The promise part here is suppose to execute the console logs but it is not getting executed. Is there something that i'm missing here. The host is the URL that we obtain when we deploy a function. Or is there some firebase or aws related plan problem. I'am using the spark plan in firebase. Thankyou.